# Where can I get early 20th century books on electronics and mathematics?

Tags: mathematics, electricity

I have been searching for books on electronics and mathematics of early 20th century.I found a link which was released in 1950 but that was in russian language.Can I find these books in universities like harvard etc?

Comment: Do you want print copies? In the past 10-15 years I've gotten most of my books simply by ordering from amazon. Do you want digital copies? Then [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22electronics%22+site:archive.org&filter=0) is one possibility (appropriately modify for mathematics or more specific topics).

Comment: Try http://gen.lib.rus.ec.

Answer (score 2):

Most of these books will be available at academic libraries. You can search on worldcat to see which academic libraries have the book near you. https://www.worldcat.org/

Comment: Unfortunately due to space issues typical university libraries have started to discard or keep older books in storage houses. Hard to get them. Only good or top class university libraries keep 18th or 19th century books.

Answer (score 1):

Internet archive is one of the best resources for historical mathematical books from the 18th/19th century. Another professional level historical resource is Hathi Trust. This is not open access.